# how to do a loop within a loop

Tags: python, django

Im trying to create a section in my application which contains a loop of catagories, and then the forms within that category. For example it should display like this:

**Category 1**

form 1

form 2

**Category 2**

form 3

*But what im actualy getting is:*

**Category 1**

form 1

form 2

form 3

**Category 2**

form 1

form 2

form 3

How can i fix this?

My view is:

```
def homepage (request):

Categories = Category.objects.all()
Forms = Form.objects.all()

output = {
    'Category_Name': Categories,
    'Form_Title': Forms,

    }

return render_to_response('forms/home.html', RequestContext(request, output))
```

And my HTML is:

```
<ul>{% for c in Category_Name %}<li>{{ c.Name }}<ul>{% for c in Form_Title %}
<li><a href="/forms/{{ c.id }}">{{ c.Title }}</a></li>{% endfor %}</ul></li>{% endfor %}</ul>
```

Comment: So...how is your application supposed to know which form goes with which category? Btw: you *do have* a loop within a loop, so you *don't* want that, or at least not in that fashion. Also, you shouldn't reuse `c` like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if your forms are associated to a category via a foreignkey

```
class Form(models.Model):
    ...
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
```

you could do something like this:

```
<ul>
    {% for c in Category_Name %}
    <li>{{ c.Name }}
        <ul>
        {% for form in c.form_set.all %}
        <li><a href="/forms/{{ form.id }}">{{ form.Title }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

take a look at the foreignkey documentation.

also note its not a good idea to use the same variable (c) in the outer and the inner loop,even if it works like in your example

and in python variable names are usually written lowercase

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def homepage (request):
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'forms/home.html', 
       {'categories': categories})
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a regroup template tag for this use case: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#regroup

An additional advantage to use regroup is, that there is only ONE sql call involved. This might be an issue if you have many categories.